# Swift Facebook SDK is not working, getting "Include of non-modular header..." ERROR

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-login

So i created a fresh project iOS/Swift project and the only thing i added was "FacebookLogin" SDK (because im trying to add a login button) with CocoaPods and its not compiling. Im getting 22 "Include of non-modular header inside framework module ..." errors in both of the the "Core" and "Login" Frameworks.

I already tried turning the "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" in "Build Settings" to "Yes" but its not helping at all. Also my Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, ‘9.0’
use_frameworks!

target 'FacebookTest' do

pod ‘FacebookLogin’

end
```

if this helps at all.

Im running Xcode 8.0 and so its up to date and i was having the same problem with the previous version.

Also here is the link to my project if checking it out helps and to check if this is a problem just on my computer or a problem with my project.

LINK: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nntcir0uqaz9zp/FacebookTest.zip?dl=0

I've been dealing with this problem for the last three days and im not making any progress so any help would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Update your cocoapods and install the pods again.